# Invalid Resx file. Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, resx

So, I`m having a little trouble with a project,

> Error 9   Invalid Resx file. Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Documents and Settings\Dragoone\Desktop\HOME01\Resources\GDWG.wav'. Line 121, position 219.    D:\Documents and Settings\Dragoone\Desktop\HOME01\Introc\Resources.resx 121 219 Introc

and the code it resembles to is the following

```
      <assembly alias="System.Windows.Forms" name="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

`..\Resources\GDWG.wav;System.IO.MemoryStream, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </data>enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the address of your .wav file and then open Windows Explorer and paste the name of the path into the address bar. If it doesn't open the .wav file then navigate to where it is, copy the full address from Explorer and add on the GDWG.wav file and then paste it into your resx file.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem and the way I solved it was to set the build action of the resource file to None when it was set to content.
[image: build action of resource]